# Override Twig form theme in Silex

Tags: php, twig, silex

How can I override parts of Twig's form theme in Silex?  I know in Symfony, all I have to do is extend the original file and then create my override blocks, but this does not seem to work in Silex.  I wanted to customize some of the parts of the bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig form theme.  Can I do this without copying the theme files into my views directory?

Here is my twig template:

```
{% extends 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block form_label_class -%}
    col-sm-4
{%- endblock form_label_class %}

{% block form_group_class -%}
    col-sm-6
{%- endblock form_group_class %}

{% block button_widget -%}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('') ~ ' btn btn-primary')|trim}) %}
    {{- parent() -}}
{%- endblock %}
```

If I place this in my views directory, Twig seems to get stuck in an infinite loop, with this file extending itself instead of its counterpart in the twig-bridge component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem:

```
$app['twig.loader.filesystem']->prependPath(__DIR__.'/../src/View/Form');
```

This tells twig to look in my scr/view/form directory where i have my template from above.  It will check this directory before using the templates in the twig bridge.